# How to counter a rogue that is 4 levels higher than the rest of the PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, rogue

So I'm running a homebrew campaign and one of my players somehow got 4 levels higher and about 40 extra hit points than they should. I don't want to call him out on it and waste precious time explaining everything. Is there a monster that is made to counter rogues? Maybe a disease? They are the only rogue and they are very convincing to everyone else, but I'm onto them. They are level 14 now while the next highest level in the party is 10. I just need to find a way to stop their health increases because they are about 20 health above the barbarian.

The party does not share experience. The rogue, (in encounters) keeps complaining about how I "nerfed them" because I thought evasion and uncanny dodge were overpowered and limited them to 5x a long rest. My argument is that they are basically a barbarian now, with all the extra hit points, but they only have 12 constitution.

Comment: By "somehow got 4 levels higher and about 40 extra HIT points than they should" do you just mean they made a mistake on their character sheet and misunderstood things? If so, can you explain why just talking to them out of session about it is a bad solution for you?

Comment: Wait, why is the solution you're looking for here to make it easier to hit rogues, rather than to confront the player? I suspect most answers will be something along those lines-- and I suspect they'll be right, since this is an out-of-game problem, and needs and out-of-game solution.

Comment: So, is the rogue getting XP from things that you don't know about? You say "you are onto them" as if they are doing something sneaky and behind you (the DM's) back. What is going on that is allowing them to level?

Comment: How *did* they get that XP ? As the GM you're the one giving the XP, did you or did you not give them 4 levels worth of extra XP ?

Comment: Do you have access to a copy of the Dungeon Masters Guide?

Comment: What do you mean by "The party does not share experience"? Are you using some home-brewed XP rules like awarding XP to the person who get's the last hit in on a monster, or something like that?

Comment: @Logan your question has been put on hold now because we don't have enough information to answer your question. Please look through the comments and edit the information into your question and we might be able to reopen it and get you some answers.

Comment: I'm also confused how the rogue has "40 extra hit points than they should" in 4 levels. With a d8 hit die and 12 con, 4 levels of Rogue should only average around ~22 hit points? Even if they rolled a max 8 at each level, with a 12 con, that's only 36 hit points.

Comment: Exactly my point

Comment: Oh wait I know the answer. Wow how did I not think of this. It's a home brew, I can do whatever I want as long as the players have fun. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Could we ascertain the age of this group?

Comment: @Logan your certainly don't have to, but if you added the extra information requested we can even provide more detailed and complete answerers than that (though I'm happy you got there). Up to you either way, but we are available to help.

Comment: This question should be preserved as an illustration of the XY problem it seems to me.  *The party does not share experience* - That key element of the homebrew was not clearly stated up front, but the assumption was "doing something about the rogue" must be the answer, or an element of an answer. The core problem is that the party is not leveling up evenly due to a structural decision. A solution that folda in that structural bit cannot now be offered.  Since the question was unclear, and closed as unclear, a solution which folded in an embedded piece of the situation can't now be provided.

Comment: [The information arrived in edit  number 7](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/71f73492-f4d6-4e0e-a303-4a75250c2d75/view-source)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Tell him after a session is over**

If you tell your player at the end of a session, that will give them enough time to redo their character at level 10. Telling them at the end of a session also allows you to bring up specific examples of when the character was unbalanced, while it’s still fresh in everyone’s minds.

Comment: We can't really do that... the party is about average level eight and I don't want to be unfair to them if they did somehow get four levels and I just whack them down.

Comment: Well you deserve it friend, I will talk to that player, because I can do anything as a DM. Thank you, have a good day.